# Inability to use "POSIX path" when passing a Applescript command via VBA's "MacScript" function

Tags: excel, applescript, vba

I'm porting some VBA from Excel 2003 (Windows XP) to Excel 2004 (OS X). Excel 2004 contains a VBA interpreter that allows you to fob off some commands onto Applescript using the **MacScript()** function.

This is all well and good for what I want to do (which is to launch files in their default application, something which on the Windows version uses an API call and is obviously incompatible with the Mac version). The code I'm using to generate the Applescript is as such:

```
sScript = "set filepath to POSIX path of """ & path & """" & Chr(13)
sScript = sScript & "try" & Chr(13)
sScript = sScript & "set command to ""open "" & quoted form of filepath" & Chr(13)
sScript = sScript & "do shell script command" & Chr(13)
sScript = sScript & "end try"
MacScript(sScript)
```

Now everything I've done and read tells me that this ought to work. It works when I run it from the Applescript Editor. And yet, it always fails, no matter what. And what is clearly failing is the "POSIX path" part. It throws a generic Error 5, "Invalid procedure call or argument," which isn't very enlightening.

This seems rather essential to its operation, and I've found zero evidence that other people have had this trouble before me. It's driving me mad. "POSIX path" seems a standard part of the Applescript definition, yet it always fails here. (It converts the file from Macintosh HD:Users:MyUserName:Blah to /Users/MyUserName/Blah.)

Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm thinking that I'll just need to write my own POSIX path function in VBA to make it work with this code, if the MacScript() function refuses to do it on its own. But I'm wary about parsing strings and etc. regarding a function I only halfway understand (the above case is easy, obviously, but I don't know how complicated it could get).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do this using a shell command and can then avoid using "posix path". Try this...

```
tell application "Finder" to open file path
```